# How do I open blue boxes?

Tags: lego-marvel-super-heroes

How do I open the blue boxes with red dots?

[image]

This is at least the second one I've seen.  There are no obvious switches or anything nearby.  My map tells me this contains a character token, the other had a gold brick I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each box has a different activation method.  This specific one requires

- Using a clawed character to dig up a switch in the nearby garden, which activates the shutters in the building the box is sitting on
- Once the shutters have been opened, a character with magnetic power can flick a switch inside the building, opening the box.

Answer (score 5):

These boxes typically have some device nearby which you can activate to open them.  Some actually have *multiple* activation triggers.  One in particular on one of the skyscrapers has three different "puzzles" you have to solve in order to open it.

I find there are little red lights nearby which turn green when you've solved some part of the opening sequence.

Usually you'll need at least one character's skills, but frequently you'll need multiple. Generally speaking, these are going to be tricky or impossible to open until you've unlocked free play for Manhattan by clearing all of the story levels.

At that point, you can switch characters at any time by holding down the "change characters" button (ie, Y or Triangle on Xbox 360/PS3).

Prior to that point, you can switch characters at vehicle call-in points, but the number of characters you're going to need for some of these makes the extra effort not worth it.